# OS Error 13 when running lein test in leiningen project clojure

Tags: testing, clojure, leiningen

I am facing an issue while running `lein test` in a clojure project directly from the terminal.
I am getting this error:

`Compilation failed: Cannot run program "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home" (in directory "/Users/iceman/IdeaProjects/sn0wst0rm"): error=13, Permission denied`

I am also running this on Mac OS

I have tried adding execution rights to the project folder, to the jdk folder, and root folder to all jdks, with nothing working out

Comment: I use https://sdkman.io/ to install JDKs on MacOS. It removes much of the manual path configuration. Also updates become easy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when I changed the jdk in .lein/profiles.clj I added the wrong path to the java executable. I added:

`:java-cmd "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-jdk-20-full.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Instead of:

`:java-cmd "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-jdk-20-full.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java"`

Leiningen is now working properly once again.